# How can i make camera commands of paraview take effect simultaneously

Tags: python, paraview

Good evening,
I have a script that rotates the camera in paraview. It looks like this.

```
camera.Elevation(45)  
camera.Roll(90) 
Render()
```

The thing is, changing the order of the commands changes the final orientation as the camera rotates the second command starting from the already rotated position.  Is there a way to make both commands take effect at the same time?
Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: It's not clear to me what the final camera orientation should be if you were somehow to apply them "at the same time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vtkCamera object, there is a method `ApplyTransform` which will allow you to apply a vtkTransform object to your camera.

vtkTransform objects have many more methods for transforms than the simple ones exposed in the vtkCamera interface. You can even use multiple transform objects to build up a transform system. If you have a transformation matrix for the camera already, you can pass it to the vtkTransform object with the `SetMatrix` method.

https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTransform.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply the two commands at the same time. Moreover, the two operations (Elevation and Roll) are noncommutative:

Indeed, you can see here:
https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView_and_Python
that Roll(angle) perform a rotation around the axis defined by **the view direction** and the origin of the dataset.

As the view direction is changed by the use or not of Elevation, so does the final result.